# Unable to load data into Ingestion time partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a blank ingestion time partitioned table with clustered by four columns. I am unable to load data in to the table. It shows below message: "Omitting INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table". How to solve it?

Comment: Can you share the code you used in and got this error?

Answer (score 9):

I think you're trying to insert data into the table without specifying the columns name:

```
insert into `project-id.dataset_id.target`
select col1,col2,col3 from `project-id.dataset_id.source`;
```

if the target is ingestion-time partitioned table, this won't work
you have to specify the columns:

```
insert into `project-id.dataset_id.target`(col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from `project-id.dataset_id.source`;
```