# Deduplicate a partitioned table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to deduplicate an ingestion-time partitioned table in BigQuery:

```
MERGE dataset.table_name targ
USING (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY _PARTITIONDATE DESC) row_number
    FROM dataset.table_name
  )
  WHERE row_number = 1
) src
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW
```

Getting the following error:

```
Omitting INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table dataset.table_name
```

1. `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` can't create partitioned tables.
2. Creating a partitioned table using DDL and then inserting requires defining schema inside the query, which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm looking for a simple universal query that I can apply to different tables with minimal adjustment. Like the one above.

Comment: `create or replace table yourdataset.table partition by date(column_name) as select ...` creates a partitoned table

Comment: it's not an ingestion-time-partitioned table.

Comment: Please take a look at this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616853/unable-to-load-data-into-ingestion-time-partitioned-table). The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#sql_1) gives following example (modified): `CREATE TABLE
  Test.newtable  (A INT64)
PARTITION BY
  _PARTITIONDATE
  OPTIONS (
    partition_expiration_days = 3,
    require_partition_filter = TRUE);` and `insert into Test.newtable (A)  values (5  )`

Comment: The docs state the following: "It is not possible to create an ingestion-time partitioned table from the result of a query. Instead, use a CREATE TABLE DDL statement to create the table, and then use an INSERT DML statement to insert data into it.". This means I have to define the schema, which is a big complication that I'm trying to avoid. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_details

Comment: You only deleting duplicates. Please replace the `on false` with `ON targ.uid=src.uid and targ._PARTITIONDATE=src._PARTITIONDATE` and remove the last `WHEN` line.

Comment: Almost there! Now I still have dups within partitions because of this statement  `targ._PARTITIONDATE=src._PARTITIONDATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the columns in the INSERT statement. You can use the following query to get the column names:

```
MERGE dataset.table_name targ
USING (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      _PARTITIONTIME,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY _PARTITIONTIME DESC) row_number
    FROM dataset.table_name
  )
  WHERE row_number = 1
) src
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (uid, _PARTITIONTIME, column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (uid, _PARTITIONTIME, column1, column2, column3)
```

But it's not universal.

Comment: Getting a syntax error: Expected keyword ROW or keyword VALUES but got "*" at [14:30]. The table is certainly ingestion-time partitioned: https://prnt.sc/5nWvrJRWi3yx

Comment: I appreciate the effort @Tibic4! However, this query is still invalid.

Comment: In this case the only way will be to specify the columns. I edited it again if it doesn't work I'll delete the answer.